# Running training op multiple times using tf.contrib.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm playing around with the tf.contrib.data.Dataset API. Basically, I have an input tensor generated by `dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).get_next()` and I can currently do something like

```
for _ in range(100):
    sess.run(train_op)
```

to repeat the train step 100 times. I don't need to feed anything, since all the inputs come from `dataset`. Doing this in a loop seems like a waste, so is there a way to tell TF to repeat the run step 100 times without having to fall back into Python code between every iteration?

I saw some similar questions about preventing the CPU-GPU transfer between iterations by feeding persistent tensors residing on the GPU, but that's a different problem.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this, since running several training iterations in one `run` would require you to update the graph several times, and each of those updates would need its own node in the graph (e.g. `Update100` depending on `Update99` depending on `Update98` etc.) - unless I'm missing some functionality in `Session`. However, avoiding the need to transfer data between Python and TF is the biggest gain, I don't think there should be a very significant difference (unless each TF iteration is really small).

Comment: I wonder if there's some simple tf.while_loop snippet that could accomplish this and you could then have a placeholder to feed the number of iterations (so you can stop and compute snapshots, etc. at regular intervals)? I've never had a reason to use a while loop before... Not sure either how much this would make a difference in terms of performance, but I'd be curious to benchmark it.

Comment: How long does your train_op take? Python overhead is around 120 usec, and you could get it down to 20usec by using (C API) pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Run instead of sess.run, at the expense of making code a lot more ugly. But also, if your train_op is so fast that this matters, then your utilization will be quite low anyway, other kinds of overhead will dominate

Comment: I get your point but if you maximise the batch size, you're effectively fully filling up the pipeline anyway (you can't do anymore than that). The raw python code execution is often much less significant.